# Error when applying tolower function to column

Tags: r, utf, tolower

When im trying to apply to lower function to data frame column:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(col1 = tolower(col1))
```

I get:

```
Error in tolower(BRIEF_DESCRIPTION), ...., IP �' in 'utf8towcs'
```

Its because some of elements in column have unknown encoding.
How could i fix it? How could i change encoding of those elements in columns with UTF-8 encoding

Comment: I think there's some strange characters.. mind using dput on df?

Comment: try to find the problematic line by subsetting the `df` or anything and give us a little reproducible example by using `dput(my_little_df)`. I normally subset the df to half of it and half again or so. There are easier ways but since you do not exactly know what to look for....

Comment: Some of elements in column have unknown encoding. How could i change encoding of those elements on columns with UTF-8 encoding